# Send Notification when new post is published in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Right now, I am sending notification to android application users when new post is created in WordPress. But issue is that, It sends notification also when draft is created and post is updated. Which condition should I put to send notification only when new post is published ?

Here is my code, located in wp-admin/includes/post.php

```
function _wp_translate_postdata( $update = false, $post_data = null ) {
    if ( $update)
        $post_data['ID'] = (int) $post_data['post_ID'];

        $post_id =  $post_data['ID'];
        global $wpdb;

        $sel2 = mysql_query("select * from gcm_users");
        while($data1  = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel2)) 
        {

            $key = $data1['gcm_regid'];
            include_once '../blogdroid/config.php';
            include_once '../blogdroid/GCM.php';

            $gcm = new GCM();
            $sel = mysql_query("select * from ".$wpdb->prefix."posts where ID='$post_id'");
            $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($sel);
            $Pname = $data['post_title'];
            $registatoin_ids = array($key);
            if($Pname != 'Auto Draft')
            {
                    $message = array("blog" => 'New Blog Arrived '.$Pname );

                    $result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids,$message);
            }

        }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to change wordpress core file? It's a very bad habit.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible to check status of post ? I mean how can I check if new post is published or it is updated ?

Comment: Try this `if( ( $_POST['post_status'] == 'publish' ) && ( $_POST['original_post_status'] != 'publish' ) ) {

  echo "New post!";

}`

Comment: Its not working for newly created post.

Comment: so you have to use `transition_post_status` action in your function.php file as mentioned @HdK answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned earlier, you really shouldn't edit WP core files. To do something you want, you can create a function and hook into [post status transitions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions), the codex has a perfect explanation about how they work.

Comment: I have created hook with draft to publish status, and works perfectly.